# How to deploy a Windows application over the internet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deployment

I have created an application using Visual studio 2015 Community Edition, in C# targeting the .Net 4.5 framework.

I originally put it up on my website for a couple of users to test, as a .zip file including all of the necessary components, but since the program is still in beta and being developed, it will require many updates so I switched to ClickOnce in order to be less annoying for my users. I have successfully deployed and even updated the ClickOnce version and seen that it automatically updates itself.

But all of my users are running into problem after problem with the download and installation. It happens with both the .zip and the setup.exe :

- Chrome flags the file as uncommonly downloaded and the user has to force the download. Following the steps for developers, Google says there's no detected problems with my website's files, so there's nothing for me to request them to review.
- Windows 8 and 10 flag the file as unsafe because it is not signed. It appears that I must pay a $180/yr fee to a third party certificate authority, to sign the file just so it is "Safe" for my users?
- Norton and a couple other antivirus software flag the file as unsafe, and even outright delete it as soon as it is installed.

Telling my users to intentionally bypass all of their security settings feels wrong, especially because to most of them I am a complete stranger. I don't see these problems with lots of other free software I download myself, but I can't find anything that gives good instructions on how to get my software to "play nice" with all this overprotective security software...

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have discovered [this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191003/how-to-prevent-my-executable-being-treated-from-av-like-bad-or-virus) which partially addresses the antivirus problem, although most of the users who have complained have been from Norton... Please note that I have indeed run my own program through virustotal.com and been given a clean bill of health on all counts.

Answer (score -1):

I've also some issues with certificates from untrusted authorities.
You can request a free trusted certificate from a real Certification Authority like this one for one year:
https://startssl.com/

May it help!
François